# Join three table by laravel eloquent model which has only one relation with each other

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

How to join the three table in Laravel Eloquent model. My table structure is like. It is easy with raw(mysql with left join) query to get the desired result, but it is possible to get via Eloquent.

### Customer table

```
 id
 title
 name
```

### Order table(has customer id)

```
  id
  customer_id
```

### Hour table (has order id)

```
 id
 order_id
```

From **Hour** model I want to get the **Customer Details** and **Order Details**. Now I am able to get the Order details like below.

```
public function order()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Order', 'order_id', 'id'); 

}
```

How to get the Customer Details?

I tried like below, but not get success

```
1.return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Models\Customer','App\Models\Order','customer_id','id');

2. return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Models\Customer','App\Models\Order','customer_id','order_id');
```

Edit 1:

```
class HourLogging extends Model
 {
    public function order()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Order', 'order_id', 'id'); 

    } 

$timeoverview = HourLogging::select('hour_logging.*')->whereRaw("hour_logging.date BETWEEN '".$start_date."' AND '".$end_date."'")->orderBy('date','asc');
$timeoverview->with('order.customer');
return $timeoverview->get();

}

class Order extends Model {


    public function customer() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Customer');
    }
}
```

Comment: Dear downvoters, please comment the reason, it will be helpfull to improve myself.

Answer (score 1):

**hasManyThrough** works the opposite way to what you're trying to achieve. It would let you get **Hour** models from your **Customer** model easily.

In order to get what you need you need to define the relations that go the other way - from **Hour** to **Order** to **Customer**. Add the following relations to your models:

```
class Hour extends Model {
  public function order() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Order');
  }
}

class Order extends Model {
  public function customer() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Customer');
  }
}
```

With those relations in place you should be able to access **Order** data with **$hour->order** and **Customer** data with **$hour->order->customer**.

One thing to remember: Eloquent offers possibility to eagerly load related data to avoid additional queries. It makes sense to do it when you fetch multiple **Hour** records at once. You an load all **Hour** records with related **Order** and **Customer** data with the following:

```
$hours = Hour::with('order.customer')->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried like your but not able to get success.

Comment: what are you getting? how are you loading data?

Comment: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::order(). Please check my Edit 1:

Comment: Well, you're loading some model HourLogging not mentioned at all, you said you wanted to get order and customer data from Hour model. The HourLogging code you pasted won't work at all, could you paste the real code?

Comment: HourLogging = Hour;

Comment: Not really, in the code you provided there are 2 different models: Hour and HourLogging

Comment: order() is defined in Hour model, that's why you're getting an error when you try to use for HourLogging

Comment: When I change change like above Order is empty.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120243/discussion-between-jedrzej-kurylo-and-vini).